# Changing default Apache page for a virtual host to a mod_autoindex generated listing

Tags: apache-2.2, directoryindex

I have the following virtual host in my Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foobarspaz
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/document/root"
</VirtualHost>
```

There is no `index.html` file in the document root directory so accessing http://foobarspaz serves up the default Apache test page for my server.

I'd like it instead to serve up a `mod_autoindex` generated directory listing of the document root instead of the default page. How would I go about this? (I'm not exactly sure how to go about 'undoing' the default page behaviour for the server root.)

Comment: Is this on centos?  Then you may want to remove /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf

Comment: Yeah, after having a look in that file that indeed would do the trick. I'm looking to solve it next to my existing configuration as it's one less step to do if the server ever needs to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markus' suggestion didn't work, but after having a look at the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` file that Christopher pointed out in his comment I tried the following inside my `VirtualHost` directive which had the desired outcome:

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options Indexes
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this might work:

```
<Directory /path/to/document/root>
   Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

And yes, as the other poster pointed out, remove the welcome.conf (in Ubuntu) or similar default config.